# How to produce a DEM from non-gridded XZY points? (Octave/MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a rather sizeable chunk of LiDAR data (a ~16-million point-cloud), which I have whittled down to X, Y, Z data (e.g):

```
436003.73  8758000.16  330.97  
436007.17  8758000.40  330.49  
436009.98  8758000.25  330.26  
436011.71  8758000.16  330.10
```

I am wanting to create a DEM of this data, yet my computer is finding this difficult due to the huge dataset. I am not particularly well-versed in MATLAB/Octave, but I am learning.
Currently I'm using the `griddata` and `meshgrid` commands, as such:

```
cd ~/Octave
dem=load('436003_ed.txt');
x=dem(:,1);
y=dem(:,2);
z=dem(:,3);
minx=min(x);
miny=min(y);
minz=min(z);
maxz=max(z);
maxx=max(x);
maxy=max(y);
rijx=minx:2:maxx;
rijy=miny:2:maxy;
[XI,YI]=meshgrid(rijx,rijy);
ZI=griddata(x,y,z,XI,YI);
```

... and that's about as far I get as it runs out of memory whilst gridding the data.

I assume part of the problem is that as I am opening the entire dataset as a variable (`dem=load('436003_ed.txt');`) as ~500MB file, which of course is very memory-expensive. I have been told about an alternative way in which I can use the `fopen` command:

```
fid=fopen('436003_ed.txt');
XYZ=fscanf(fid,'%f %f  %f');
```

However this seems to provide an odd format, as is itself not loaded into the RAM?

Is there possibly a way in which I can load it line by line, placing each Z value into the appropriate DEM cell, whilst counting the total elevation for that cell, and the number of hits (so I can then average the elevation afterwards) to produce a DEM? This will negate the use of the `meshgrid` and `griddata` commands.
Being entirely new at this I don't know which commands to look up and play around with!

Many thanks in advance. I have MATLAB R2013b, and I've been doing some of this via Octave too if this helps.

**UPDATE**
I solved the problem using some a command line tool library called GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/ GDAL grid, specifically). This helped me grid the data. Whilst this is an answer to my query, it is not the extact answer I was looking for.
Whilst my original method would potentially work, if my computer had enough memory, there are alternative ways to script this in MATLAB - using the `fscanf` and `fopen` commands - I have yet discovered how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Octave currently uses GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick for image IO. However, both of this projects deal with integers only and your data is floating point so you won't be able to use the typical `imwrite` function to save this as an image. If you really want to save it as an image, you can for example code your own interface to libtiff. I believe Matlab can handle floating point images though.

About your code, I don't know what you may do about running out of memory but you have some unnecessary lines. You can replace:

```
x=dem(:,1);
y=dem(:,2);
z=dem(:,3);
minx=min(x);
miny=min(y);
minz=min(z);
maxz=max(z);
maxx=max(x);
maxy=max(y);
rijx=minx:2:maxx;
rijy=miny:2:maxy;
```

with:

```
mins = min (dem);
maxs = max (dem);
rijx = mins(1):2:maxs(1);
rijy = mins(2):2:maxs(2);
```

Comment: So if Matlab does cope with floating point I should be able to use the typical `imwrite` function?  

Thanks for clarifying some of the code - a few lines less to deal with! However, without a way to split the dataset, or perhaps get it to write to file as it does it (so it doesn't store it all in memory) I won't be able to get much further.